# MIPS Assembly programming

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a quick question. I'm using MARS assembler (programming in the MIPS instruction set) and I have 4 files MIPS files. One file contains my main method to be run and it calls a function in the other file. My function has the .globl directive before it, but every time I try and compile my program I get below error. I'm not sre where I'm going wrong and I have 'Initialize Program Counter to Global 'main' checked in the setting

Assemble: assembling C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Test\main.asm, C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Test\gameStarts.asm, 
C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Test\summary.asm, C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Test\validating.asm

Error in C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Test\gameStarts.asm line 7 column 10: Symbol "printLoading" not found in symbol table.
Assemble: operation completed with errors.

**In main.asm, I have,

```
.data
    #gameStarts.asm
    fileName:       .space  8
    fileContents:       .space  50000
    legalWords:     .space  50000
    correctWords:       .space  50000       
    currentWord:        .asciiz "            "
    availableLetters:   .asciiz "            "
    lettersInGrid:      .asciiz "         "
    printLoading:       .asciiz "\nPlease wait while your game loads...\n\n\n"
    timeOverMessage:    .asciiz "\n\n!!!OUT OF TIME!!!\n"
    successMessage1:    .asciiz "\nYou have entered "
    successMessage2:    .asciiz " correct words!\n"
```

.
.
.

In gameStarts, I have

```
#------------------------------------Import File------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Generates random file name
# Imports dictionary file

startGame:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, printLoading
    syscall

getRandomFileName:

    li   $a0, 0 #set lower bound for random int
    li   $a1, 25    #set upper boind for random int
    li   $v0, 42       # random int w/range
    syscall
    addi $a0, $a0, 65   #bring $v0 into range of Alphabet in Ascii table
    la $t1, fileName    #load address where we store filename
    sb $a0, ($t1)   # store the random letter in filename at position 0
    sb $zero, 1($t1)    #add a null character to end of fileName
```

.
.
.
.
.

Comment: _"My function has the .globl directive before it"_ But the error message is clearly referring to `printLoading`.

Comment: printLoading is included in the main.asm and the function has the .globl directive

Comment: What you should be making global are all the symbols that you want to be able to use in other source files, such as `printLoading`.